# node-sppkg-deploy erroneously tries to GET https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/AppCatalog/_api/site?$select=Id

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sharepoint, promise

I'm trying to upload and deploy packages using gulp.
The logic to upload works but when I try to deploy, I get the following errors:

```
dev:test-plugins admin$ gulp upload-sequential
Build target: DEBUG
[12:04:50] Using gulpfile /src/test-plugins/gulpfile.js
[12:04:50] Starting gulp
[12:04:50] Starting 'upload-sequential'...
[12:04:51] Uploading testpackage.sppkg
[12:04:52] Upload successful 1523ms
[12:04:52] Published file 333ms
======https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/AppCatalog
(node:75514) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Failed to call the API URL: https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/AppCatalog/_api/site?$select=Id
(node:75514) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:75514) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
About to exit with code: 0
Process terminated before summary could be written, possible error in async code not continuing!
Trying to exit with exit code 1
```

The error is correct, there is no such URL as https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/AppCatalog/_api/site?$select=Id  and I don't know why it's trying to GET that site.

The correct site is:

```
 https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/
```

And the catalog site is:

```
 https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/AppCatalog
```

**Code**

Here's the code:

```
build.task("upload-sequential", {
  execute: async () => {
      const pluginList = require("./config/apps.json");
      if (!pluginList) {
        return;
      }
      for (const { name, sites } of pluginList.plugins) {
        const folderLocation = `./plugins/${name}`;
        if (!sites) {
          //deploy to tenant
        } else {
              for (const site of sites) {
                try{
                      return new Promise((resolve) => {
                        gulp
                          .src(folderLocation)
                          .pipe(
                            spsync({
                              username: uname,
                              password: pwd,
                              site: siteUrl + site,
                              libraryPath: appCatalog,
                              publish: true,
                            })
                          )
                          
                          .on("finish",(resolve)=> {
                            console.log("======" + coreOptions.siteUrl + site + "/" + coreOptions.appCatalog);
                             sppkgDeploy.deploy({
                              username: uname,
                              password: pwd,
                              absoluteUrl: siteUrl + site + "/" + appCatalog,
                              filename: name,
                              skipFeatureDeployment: true,
                              verbose: false
                          })
                        });
                      });
                    }
                    catch (error){
                      console.log("*******");
                      console.log(error);
                      console.log("******");
                    }
                }
            }
      }
  },
});
```

**What I've tried so far:**

I tried to turned on verbose logging for the node-sppkg-deploy like this: (last line)

```
 .on("finish",(resolve)=> {
   console.log("======" + coreOptions.siteUrl + site + "/" + coreOptions.appCatalog);
   sppkgDeploy.deploy({
     username: creds.username,
     password: creds.password,
     absoluteUrl: coreOptions.siteUrl + site + "/" + coreOptions.appCatalog,
     filename: name,
     skipFeatureDeployment: true,
     verbose: true
 })
```

And I see this type of output:

```
Build target: DEBUG
[12:02:19] Using gulpfile /src/test-plugins/gulpfile.js
[12:02:19] Starting gulp
[12:02:19] Starting 'upload-sequential'...
[12:02:19] Uploading testpackage.sppkg
[12:02:21] Upload successful 2351ms
[12:02:22] Published file 364ms
======https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/AppCatalog
ERROR: { StatusCodeError: 404 - undefined
    at new StatusCodeError (/src/test-plugins/node_modules/node-sppkg-deploy/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:32:15)
    at Request.plumbing.callback (/src/test-plugins/node_modules/node-sppkg-deploy/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:104:33)
    at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/src/test-plugins/node_modules/node-sppkg-deploy/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)
    at Request.self.callback (/src/test-plugins/node_modules/node-sppkg-deploy/node_modules/request/request.js:188:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/src/test-plugins/node_modules/node-sppkg-deploy/node_modules/request/request.js:1171:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/src/test-plugins/node_modules/node-sppkg-deploy/node_modules/request/request.js:1091:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  name: 'StatusCodeError',
  statusCode: 404,
  message: '404 - undefined',
  error: undefined,
  options:
   { method: 'GET',
     url:
      'https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/AppCatalog/_api/site?$select=Id',
     resolveWithFullResponse: true,
     simple: true,
     headers:
```

Also, tried to use tenant & site properies in the node sppkg deploy call but I get the same error.

I uploaded and deployed the package manually, using the same credentials on the same site and it works fine.

I'm not sure what else to check.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't resolve promises. I add a `resolve()` in `on(finish)`.

Also, I think you should await your promises instead of returning them.

Another point is you may need to handle the error in your `gulp.pipe`, once there is an error, you should `reject()`. I add this part of logic, you may have a look at it.

```js
build.task("upload-sequential", {
  execute: async () => {
    const pluginList = require("./config/apps.json");
    if (!pluginList) {
      return;
    }
    for (const { name, sites } of pluginList.plugins) {
      const folderLocation = `./plugins/${name}`;
      if (!sites) {
        //deploy to tenant
      } else {
        for (const site of sites) {
          try {
            await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              gulp
                .src(folderLocation)
                .pipe(
                  spsync({
                    username: uname,
                    password: pwd,
                    site: siteUrl + site,
                    libraryPath: appCatalog,
                    publish: true,
                  })
                )
                .on("error", reject)
                .on("finish", resolve);
            });

            sppkgDeploy.deploy({
              username: uname,
              password: pwd,
              absoluteUrl: siteUrl + site + "/" + appCatalog,
              filename: name,
              skipFeatureDeployment: true,
              verbose: false,
            });
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            throw new Error(error);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: if i did want to add a reject, what would it look like?  meaning where would I put it?

Comment: @dot, I updated my asnwer and added on(error) in pipe() and reject in the callback function.